# Access props of React component which hasnt rendered yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loading screen in my project and I would like to fade it away once my landing page( its a video) has loaded. I figured I could use the onLoadedData prop of the video element to set the state of my app, appLoaded to true. But because it's not rendered I can't access it. So how would I go about something like this?

the simplified version of my code is:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {appLoaded: false}
    }

    loadApp = () => {this.setState({appLoaded:true});}

    render () {
        const { appLoaded } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="App">
                    {appLoaded ? 
                       (
                        <Switch>
                         <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => <Home {...props} loadApp={this.loadApp}/>}/>
                        </Switch>
                        ) 
                        : (<LoadingScreen/>
                )
      }
}

export default App
```

And in my home component, I call the loadApp function passed down by **App.js**

```
const Home = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className="home-container" style={{width:"100%"}}>
                <video onLoadedData = this.props.loadApp/>
            </div>
        );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The video won't start loading until you actually render it, so you will have to either "hide" it with CSS until it's ready to be played or you will have to make an HTTP request to grab data/blob for the video and then render your `video` element with that info... also, `loadeddata` wouldn't really give you want you want - `canplaythrough` would be the closest to what you'd want to use.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 0):

There is no `this` in functional components. Change **Home** component to the following:

```js
const Home = props => {
        return (
            <div className="home-container" style={{width:"100%"}}>
                <video onLoadedData={props.loadApp}/>
            </div>
        );
};
```